# How to clear the text from a EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I tried with `.getText().clear()` and `.setText("")`, but it doesn't work. Any idea why? I try to clear the text from all the EditTexts when the NewEventButton is pressed. If you have an idea, please add some code. Thanks!

Java:

```
package com.exemple.android.calendar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NewEventActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //step 1.A:create objects

    public EditText DayEditText;
    public EditText MonthEditText;
    public EditText YearEditText;
    public EditText StartingHourEditText;
    public EditText StartingMinuteEditText;
    public EditText EndingHourEditText;
    public EditText EndingMinuteEditText;
    public EditText Title;
    public RadioGroup answer1;
    public Button NewEventButton;

    int day, month, year, s_hour, s_min, e_hour, e_min;
    String title;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_event_page);

        //Step 1.B: assign objects

        DayEditText = findViewById(R.id.DayEditText);
        MonthEditText = findViewById(R.id.MonthEditText);
        YearEditText = findViewById(R.id.YearEditText);
        StartingHourEditText = findViewById(R.id.StartingHourEditText);
        StartingMinuteEditText = findViewById(R.id.StartingMinuteEditText);
        EndingHourEditText = findViewById(R.id.EndingHourEditText);
        EndingMinuteEditText = findViewById(R.id.EndingMinuteEditText);
        Title = findViewById(R.id.TitleEditText);
        answer1 = findViewById(R.id.Answer1);
        NewEventButton = findViewById(R.id.CreateEventButton);

        DayEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MinMaxFilter("0", "31")});
        MonthEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MinMaxFilter("0", "12")});
        YearEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MinMaxFilter("0", "2030")});
        StartingHourEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MinMaxFilter("0", "24")});
        StartingMinuteEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MinMaxFilter("0", "59")});
        EndingHourEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MinMaxFilter("0", "24")});
        EndingMinuteEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MinMaxFilter("0", "59")});
        //Step 2: get data into variables

        //Step 2.B: get data and assign
        //PROBLEM: If we just extract, the code won't be run because there's nothing to extract yet. We need a conditional.
        //SOLUTION: Create a condition for pressing the button, and then extract the variables when the button is pressed.

        TextWatcher dayTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                day = Integer.parseInt(DayEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        };
        TextWatcher monthTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                month = Integer.parseInt(MonthEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        };
        TextWatcher yearTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                year = Integer.parseInt(YearEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        };
        TextWatcher titleTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                title = Title.getText().toString();
            }
        };
        TextWatcher s_hourTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                s_hour = Integer.parseInt(StartingHourEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        };
        TextWatcher s_minTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                s_min = Integer.parseInt(StartingMinuteEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        };
        TextWatcher e_minTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                e_min = Integer.parseInt(EndingMinuteEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        };
        TextWatcher e_hourTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                e_hour = Integer.parseInt(EndingHourEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        };

        DayEditText.addTextChangedListener(dayTextWatcher);
        MonthEditText.addTextChangedListener(monthTextWatcher);
        YearEditText.addTextChangedListener(yearTextWatcher);
        Title.addTextChangedListener(titleTextWatcher);
        StartingMinuteEditText.addTextChangedListener(s_minTextWatcher);
        StartingHourEditText.addTextChangedListener(s_hourTextWatcher);
        EndingMinuteEditText.addTextChangedListener(e_minTextWatcher);
        EndingHourEditText.addTextChangedListener(e_hourTextWatcher);

        NewEventButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                answer1.clearCheck();
                Intent agendaPageGoing = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AgendaActivity.class);
                startActivity(agendaPageGoing);

                //HERE IS WHERE IT SHOULD GO
            }
        });



    }
}
```

PS: the app is a calendar. After going through all the code, I need some variables and to get to Agenda. Also, the fields should be cleared.

Comment: "it doesn't work" -- it does in general. Your code does not show your use of either of these approaches. Bear in mind that your code will automatically fill in new text after you clear it, courtesy of your `TextWatcher` objects.